# Any known way to check assembly files for syntax errors

Tags: assembly, arm, syntax-checking

Im searching for an way to check if any syntax errors are present in a assembly file for arm. My first try were to query all possible instructions of the arch x. 
My next attempt was to look for any known syntax checker as a thought that inventing the wheel might be a overkill.
My primary goal is to get a nice syntax checker and or autocomplete as an vim plugin.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: The normal way is to try assembling it.  Any decent assembler will report syntax errors with line numbers.  Since most assembly languages include a macro language, a list of valid mnemonics is not sufficient check one line in isolation.

Comment: But overall asm syntax is line-oriented and simple, so there's some hope for autocomplete of mnemonics as the first token on a line.  (I wouldn't worry about completing mnemonics for lines that already have a label; people whole put `label: mnemonic` on the same line are weird.)